# multiple pages with github repository

Tags: html, github, repository

hey im hosting a website with github and added multiple pages it works offline but when i publish it it comes up with a 404 error saying "If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL.For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file." i have no idea how i could do this i tried putting all the html files in a folder but it did nothing, any advice?

repository https://github.com/BigRig420/RNR-Games

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works. https://bigrig420.github.io/RNR-Games/

Just be sure that Github finishes upload your files to server. There will be a little green icon after finished.

Also be sure that, cleaning your cache.

Comment: sick thank you i was just pressing th projects button whick was messing up and didnt even bother trying the others cheers